# SSRS This feature is not available?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-express, ssrs-2012

Ive installed SSRS on my local machine, we want to test it before we deploy it for the whole system. It is running off SQL 2012 Express edition (this maybe why- however if it is then ssrs is virtually unusable on express?).

I keep getting error messages saying: This feature is not available in this edition of SSRS.

-Its when I do things like:
save a dataset?
Try to access the report builder?
try to update security settings?
Any Idea's guys?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SSRS Edition comparison chart here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Reporting

Express lacks a *lot* of features, and is not going to suitably reflect what you'll be seeing with Standard or Enterprise edition.  If your Production plans involve a higher tier sku, I'd suggest skipping this Express test, and just grab a 180 day trial of SQL Server and try out the same version you'll be using in Production.

Comment: Thank you, however it says the features are available. Ie) Report Builder. -When I click on it in the report manager it says its not available... hmmm....

Cheers anyway!

Comment: Report Builder absolutely works with express; it's just the button to install/launch via the portal that does not work.  You can grab the standalone alone installer and use that with express.  Again though, these issues are exactly why using Express to "evaluate" the product is a terrible idea.